# iri Node with Nelson not fully synced

Tags: iri-node

I installed my iri node with nelson about a weeks ago and it is still not synced.

Does anyone have any suggestions why?

#### Adding more info to setup.

I am running arch linux. I installed iri with yaourt from the aur.
I installed nelson from a build, and confirmed that it is working. It has synced quite a bit.
Let me know if there is any more info I can provide.

Comment: Please add more information about your setup. Otherwise we're guessing...

Answer (score 2):

Please try installing iri-1.4.1.6 and nelson 0.3.12. You might need to re-download database snapshot before. Had some trouble with the "old" database.

Answer (score 1):

To speed up the sync, you can first download a recent Database.  You must stop IRI first before attempting to extract the DB.  Restart IRI.

Following the instructions from http://iota.partners/  go to Step 6.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in IRI 1.4.1.4 which prevents node from syncing. A patch is being tested. You can try https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/issues/428#issuecomment-354794138